# How can I make a copy of a table from information_schema?

Tags: mariadb, information-schema

I would like to extract meta information from information_schema like count of rows in a table and store the result table into "meta" database. However, while I can query tables in information_schema, I can't store the result into a table. Following query always returns "ok", but it doesn't produce the table (I can rerun the query and MariaDB still returns "ok"):

```
create table meta.copy as 
select *
from information_schema.`TABLES`
```

What is more interesting is that if I thoroughly avoid databases (TABLE_SCHEMAs) with a view, I can save the partial copy of information_schema.TABLES. For example, following query works:

```
create table meta.copy as 
select *
from information_schema.`TABLES`
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'performance_schema'
```

Is this a quirk of MariaDB 10.0.15? Or is there some rationale behind this behavior? And is there a query that can make complete copies of tables from information_schema?

PS: I know I can extract count of rows other ways but I also want to extract other information from information_schema than count of rows.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: It could be a bug - I can confirm that I can make a full copy of information_schema.TABLES in Mysql 5.6.21, even though the data are the same.